# How to embed bing map with custom push pin

Tags: bing-maps

I want to embed a Bing map with a custom push pin.
Here is my code:-

```
<div>
        <iframe width="500" height="400" frameborder="0" src="http://www.bing.com/maps/embed/viewer.aspx?v=3&cp=20.327496~85.818374&lvl=18&w=500&h=400&sty=r&typ=d&pp=~~20.327496~85.817961&ps=&dir=0&mkt=en-in&src=SHELL&form=BMEMJS"></iframe>
        <div style="margin: 12px 0 0 0;">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bing.com/maps/?cp=20.327496~85.818374&sty=r&lvl=18&where1=20.327496,85.817961&mm_embed=map">View Larger Map</a>
            &nbsp; |&nbsp; 
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.bing.com/maps/?cp=20.327496~85.818374&sty=r&lvl=18&rtp=~pos.20.327496_85.817961__&mm_embed=dir">Get Directions</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

you could use a code like this one :

```
="<div><iframe width='300' height='200' frameborder='0' src='http://www.bing.com/maps/embed/viewer.aspx?v=3&cp="&Latitude&"~"&Longitude&"&lvl=17&w=300&h=200&sty=r&typ=s&pp=~~"&Latitude&"~"&Longitude&"&ps=55&dir=0&mkt=en-gb&src=SHELL&form=BMEMJS'></iframe></div>"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to customize the embedded maps. If you want to create a custom map you will need to use the full Bing Maps API.